# MySQL Server 8.0 - No bin file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have been trying to reset my password for MySQL in order to use the DBMS appropriately for an application I am working on. I have looked at numerous threads for resetting your password on MySQL and the only way is to go through the command prompt I have noticed.

Every method I have seen requires being able to access the bin file such as:

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
```

However, for MySQL Server 8.0 there is no "bin" file following the 'MySQL Server 8.0'.

Does anyone know a way around this so that I can reset my password?

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with `mysql-workbench`, so I assume you would accept a solution that involves this tool. If you have your old password still, you can simply log in to your server with that password, go to `Administration -> Users and Privileges`:

[image]

There you can enter a new password.

Comment: That sure does look handy, however I do not believe that my workbench version, 8.0, has this 'Administration' feature. I cannot seem to locate it on my workbench.

Comment: It surely has. It just might look a bit different, as some details changed over time. Best is to get the latest version (8.0.17 currently).